# SORT_NATURAL, SORT_FLAG_CASE works only with SORT_ASC

Tags: php, array-multisort

I'm having an issue using array_multisort. Based on other questions on stackoverflow and in a couple other places around the web, you should be able to sort case insensitively by using the following:

```
        $columnSort = array();
        foreach ($accounts as $key => $row) {
            $columnSort[$key] = $row[$columnToSortBy];
        }
        array_multisort($columnSort,SORT_ASC|SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE, $accounts);
```

Note: the above code works great for me. However, as soon as I tweak the flag to SORT_DESC|SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE, where I've only changed it from SORT_ASC to SORT_DESC, I get an "array_multisort(): Argument #2 is an unknown sort flag" error.

I've googled around and can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Read the docs for [array_multisort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), and you'll find that you don't use the `|` (bitwise or) operator, but specify each flag individually.... `array_multisort($columnSort,SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL, SORT_FLAG_CASE, $accounts);`

Comment: combining the sort flags with bitwise should also work: `array_multisort($columnSort,SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE, $accounts);`